# SVN subversion on USB pin drive?

Tags: svn

Not ever sure if it can be done, but is it possible to use a USB pin drive to host subversion for my projects source control? Or does it have to be setup on a remote server? I have a Linux dedicated server, how difficult would it be setup one on it?

Never setup anything like this myself... a bit fuzzy about the whole concept.

Any info would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am using an free SVN in the cloud: https://www.assembla.com/. You can have an repository public or private. It's very useful!

I hope to have helped you.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well you can put the subversion repository on the usb pin drive but I'm not sure what advantage you'll get if you do so since if you remove the usb on put it on another computer you'll need to install the server software again and configure it. Just setup it on your Linux server. To setup the server, it'll depends on your linux distro so just google it : How to install svn server on LINUX_DISTRO

Comment: Since all my sites are on this server, I'd probably be better of setting it on another server. But I will check out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the repository on a thumb drive.  Odds are you will use the file protocol; however, a repository on a drive won't generally be shared with other developers, so it is sort of a one-person solution.  Much of the value of a source code control system comes from sharing the repository across a team of developers.

Comment: Well, in this project I am it  :)

Comment: Then `svn checkout` with a file URL sounds like a good solution for you.  Later, if you decide you need to expand, you can always add the other, networked, protocols on top of the repository.